# Serialize list of child objects to root-level elements

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

I'm attempting to serialize a parent object containing a `List` of children into XML which consists of a parent element with each child object as a separate element. I'd like this to apply any time the child type is serialized, so implementing `IXmlSerializable` on the child seems ideal; however, I have not found a self-contained solution. Alternatively, possibly providing an `XmlAttributeOverrides` to the `XmlSerializer`? I don't mind having to add attributes on the Parent, but would like to avoid any ISerializable implementation on the Parent (as I have many types which could have references to Child).

Example class hierarchy:

```
public class Parent {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string SomeProperty { get; set; }
// ....
    public List<Child> Children { get; set; }
}

public class Child { 
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}

var o = new Parent {
   Name = "Test Parent",
   Children = new List<Child> {
      new Child { Name = "Alice", Value = "This is alice's value" },
      new Child { Name = "Bob", Value = "This is bob's value" }
   }
};
```

Should serialize to:

```
<Parent>
  <Name>Test Parent</Name>
  <Alice>This is alice's value</Alice>
  <Bob>This is bob's value</Bob>
</Parent>
```

I have created a IXmlSerializable implementation on Child as:

```
public void WriteXml(XmlWriter writer) {     
   writer.WriteElementString(Name, Value.ToString());
}
```

And added `[XmlElement]` on `Children`.
Which correctly serializes the child, but it will still be nested one level too deep under the Parent, e.g.:

```
<Parent>
  <Children>
    <Alice>this is alice</Alice>
 </Children>
</Parent>
```

Hopefully I'm missing some trick. Thanks!

Comment: I propose you look different at this. You want to cut out the list element of children, why would you do this? The serialization is good already. Does that make sense?

Comment: [XmlElement] should be above : public List<Child> Children { get; set; }

Comment: @Aldert I am working within the bounds of a legacy system which I'm interfacing with. I need to write the XML in an expected format, yet these collection items will be added dynamically at runtime.

Comment: Ok, now I understand your limitations..

Answer (score 1):

Per [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.serialization.ixmlserializable.writexml?view=netframework-4.8):

> The WriteXml implementation you provide should write out the XML representation of the object. **The framework writes a wrapper element and positions the XML writer after its start**. Your implementation may write its contents, including child elements. **The framework then closes the wrapper element.**

So when serializing `Parent` the framework will write `Children` and then multiple `Child` elements, calling your `IXmlSerializable.WriteXml` implementation on `Child` for each to write their *contents*.

If you add `[XmlElement]` to `Children`, then it will write multiple `Children` elements (as that's the name of the property) and then call your implementation for each child.

Given how this works, I'm not sure you have any other option other than to implement `IXmlSerializable` in `Parent`.

Comment: Thanks, I had figured as much but was hoping some attribute may have helped with this. It looks like I will have to work this into some kind of serialization factory.